# Include top level directory into zip file created by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zip

The code below zips the following files:

```
c:\test\1.txt
c:\test\2.txt
c:\test\3.txt
```

into test.zip like:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

but what I would like is to include the directory test:

```
test\1.txt
test\2.txt
test\3.txt
```

Any idea on how to do this?

```
$zipFilename = 'c:\test.zip'
$zipDir = 'c:\test'

Set-Content $zipFilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zipPackage = $shell.NameSpace($zipFilename)

Get-ChildItem $zipDir -Recurse | foreach {
    # echo $_.FullName
    $zipPackage.CopyHere($_.FullName)
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a reason to loop through the files?
You could just skip the loop and outright zip the files/folder structure

```
$zipFilename = 'c:\test.zip'
$zipDir = 'c:\test'

Set-Content $zipFilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zipPackage = $shell.NameSpace($zipFilename)

$zipPackage.CopyHere($zipDir)
```

If you have additional processing you could add a dynamic sleep. Wait a second per file.

```
Sleep (Get-childitem $zipDir -recurse | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expandproperty Count)
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I missed the obvious!